# How to generate/calculate vertices of dodecahedron?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graphics

How can I algorithmically generate the vertices of dodecahedron?

I would like the tetrahedron's centroid to be at `(0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Certainly not a good question for Stack Overflow. Google may solve this question in few seconds.

Comment: I've never understood why such questions are frowned upon here.

Comment: @Louis, while it's an interesting problem, it shows no effort, no research, and is pure mathematics rather than programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the question is now the top result for a Google search (the dupe at math is #2), I figured I might as well add some code.

A full console program is below and should compile and run and be generally self-explanatory.

The algorithm was based on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates) (thank you, [mt_ from math.stackoverflow.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141304/how-to-calculate-vertices-of-dodecahedron#comment325431_141304))

This code should print a correct list of vertices for you. Your concern is mostly with the method `Program.MakeDodecahedron`, however don't just copy and paste it because you need to modify this to use your own vertex data structure instead of my mock `Vertex` object. You could easily use [XNA's Vector3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector3.aspx), which has a constructor with the exact same signature as my `Vertex`. Also because my `Vertex.ToString` method is hacky, this program may print an ugly output table when used with `Vector3` so keep that in mind.

Also, note that this is a(n imprefect) demonstration. For instance, if generating many tetrahedra, you would be needlessly recalculating constants (such as the golden ratio) for each call.

With XNA, especially if you use `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`, you can also easily render your dodecahedron in 3D. You can adapt the code from [this tutorial](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/a-little-practice) for this purpose.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DodecahedronVertices
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Size parameter: This is distance of each vector from origin
            var r = Math.Sqrt(3);

            Console.WriteLine("Generating a dodecahedron with enclosing sphere radius: " + r);

            // Make the vertices
            var dodecahedron = MakeDodecahedron(r);

            // Print them out
            Console.WriteLine("       X        Y        Z");
            Console.WriteLine("   ==========================");
            for (var i = 0; i < dodecahedron.Count; i++)
            {
                var vertex = dodecahedron[i];
                Console.WriteLine("{0,2}:" + vertex, i + 1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nDone!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a list of vertices (in arbitrary order) for a tetrahedron centered on the origin.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="r">The distance of each vertex from origin.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static IList<Vertex> MakeDodecahedron(double r)
        {
            // Calculate constants that will be used to generate vertices
            var phi = (float)(Math.Sqrt(5) - 1) / 2; // The golden ratio

            var a = 1 / Math.Sqrt(3);
            var b = a / phi;
            var c = a * phi;

            // Generate each vertex
            var vertices = new List<Vertex>();
            foreach (var i in new[] { -1, 1 })
            {
                foreach (var j in new[] { -1, 1 })
                {
                    vertices.Add(new Vertex(
                                        0,
                                        i * c * r,
                                        j * b * r));
                    vertices.Add(new Vertex(
                                        i * c * r,
                                        j * b * r,
                                        0));
                    vertices.Add(new Vertex(
                                        i * b * r,
                                        0,
                                        j * c * r));

                    foreach (var k in new[] { -1, 1 })
                        vertices.Add(new Vertex(
                                            i * a * r,
                                            j * a * r,
                                            k * a * r));
                }
            }
            return vertices;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A placeholder class to store data on a point in space. Don't actually use this, write a better class (or just use Vector3 from XNA).
    /// </summary>
    class Vertex
    {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;

        public Vertex(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var s = String.Format("{0,8:F2},{1,8:F2},{2,8:F2}", x, y, z);

            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

As my code is probably quite verbose and spread out, I'd recommend reading it in something which supports folding of for-loops and other code structures.

Comment: @user1782020 Thank you for finding and correcting the bug! Apparently I don't have enough rep to act on your edit, and it seemed to be getting rejected, so I hope you don't mind that I stole your corrections and edited the answer myself.

Comment: Namespace "TetrahedronVertices"?

Comment: @Xenotoad Uh, yes? What is the question?

Comment: Why is a = (R * 1) needed? why is it just a = R, or just no a at all? (thanks for the code, it is very clean otherwise)

Comment: @Snowman Eh, it's been 3 years since I wrote this, so your guess is as good as mine. Let me see.

Comment: @Snowman Well, I checked it again and actually found a bug, the radius of enclosing sphere is completely off. `a` probably existed to adjust that, but I must have gotten confused somewhere. Anyhow, I fixed the code - when you ask for a dodecahedron with enclosing sphere of radius `sqrt(3)` it appears to give the numbers Wikipedia says it should.

Comment: @Xenotoad Lol, I **finally** figured out what it was you were asking about. Also fixed! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I felt that there is an error there. (nice foreaches)

Comment: Here's working fiddle based on this code:  https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/Aai

Answer (score 11):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates):

> The following Cartesian coordinates define the vertices of a
> dodecahedron centered at the origin and suitably scaled and
> oriented:
>
> (±1, ±1, ±1)
>
> (0, ±1/φ, ±φ)
>
> (±1/φ, ±φ, 0)
>
> (±φ, 0, ±1/φ)
>
> where φ = (1 + √5) / 2 is the golden ratio (also written τ) ≈ 1.618.
> The edge length is 2/φ = √5 – 1. The containing sphere has a radius of
> √3.

I find that this description is way more concise and informative than a big piece of C# code. (-:

Answer (score 2):

The Cartesian coordinates of a dodecahedron centered at P(0, 0, 0) and vertices bounded by a sphere of radius r are given by:

P(± r/√3, ± r/√3, ± r/√3)

P(0, ± r/(√3*φ), ± (r*φ)/√3)

P(± r/(√3*φ), ± (r*φ)/√3, 0)

P(± (r*φ)/√3, 0, ± r/(√3*φ))

> where φ = (1 + √5) / 2 is the golden ratio (also written τ) ≈ 1.618.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Riemann surface stereographic projection centered at a 0 vertex. (Sorry, I can't find how to post math symbols)

Where T is the golden ratio, let a = 1/T^2 and let the complex conjugate pair b+-ic be defined with b=sqrt(5)/4 and c=sqrt(3)/4. Rotate these three points by 0, 120, and 240 degrees so you now have nine points, all inside the unit circle.

Map every point to an image outside the unit circle using the map z -> -1/z. Add a point at zero and infinity and you now have all the vertices of the dodecahedron.

If you want your dodecahedron on the sphere, do the usual stereographic back-map, making the unit circle go onto the equator. By the usual process of inscribing, this also gives you a vertex-centered cube or tetrahedron, but rotated by about 37.76 or 22.24 degrees respectively.